# What is the best place to put ASP.NET MVC FormMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, membership, membership-provider

I have a project using asp.net mvc and form membership provider .

I have a Domain layer ( with Entities , Services , and repositories ) .
I also have a UI layer ( with controllers , filters , IoC , ViewModels, views ).

what is the best place to put my FormMembershipProvider ?

Comment: You might benefit from investigating my approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964989/how-to-pass-current-user-information-to-all-layers-in-ddd/3969014#3969014 I'm avoiding `FormMembershipProvider` altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Membership is a concern of your web app not your domain so it should go in the web app (UI layer).

Comment: It's not that simple. Provider itself should not live in domain, but knowledge about access rights should. Problem is - asp.net membership provider is quite invasive.

Comment: "but knowledge about access rights should"- i disagree. I believe the web app is a human interface to the business of the domain and as such mandates external [to the domain] concerns like authentication, roles/access/etc. While these external concerns make their way into the domain/data this is only due to the software acting as a solution. Without the software/web-app perhaps these concerns would not exist. I could be wrong here especially as MVC forces us into certain corners. Perhaps a Bounded Context is required in the domain to facilitate these MVC/web-specific concerns?